# Can someone explain "access arguments" in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can someone explain "access arguments" in Drupal? Trust me I have tried Googling it but I am just not getting a clear grasp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in /admin/user/permissions you will see lots of access options. they come from drupal modules, and lets the site administrator distribute specific permissions to user roles (drupal provides 'anonymous' and 'registered' roles by default).
modules declare them through [hook_perm](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_perm/6) and they are as easy to use as:

```
function mymodulename_perm {
return array('use custom feature', 'use the other custom feature');
}
```

and they will show up there, ready to be used. now, in any function of yours, you can check for user access through [user_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_access/6) which is just as easy to use:

```
if (user_access('use custom feature')) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: and if you're wondering how to use this on hook_menu, just set 'access arguments' => 'use custom feature' on your menu item. 'access callback' is set to user_access by default, but might be overridden (check http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6 for more details)

Comment: For Drupal 7 the function is called [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7)

Comment: Hi could you check out my question, its some what similar but I am using drupal 7 http://stackoverflow.com/q/22832569/1877909

Answer (score 9):

Access arguments are the arguments passed to the function that checks if a user has access to a menu.

Given a menu callback definition as the following

```
  $items['blog/feed'] = array(
    'title' => 'RSS feed',
    'page callback' => 'blog_feed',
    'access callback' => 'custom_module_blog_access',
    'access arguments' => array('feed'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

The function `custom_module_blog_access()` will be called as `custom_module_blog_access('feed')`. If the function returns `TRUE`, then the user will be given access to the menu callback; differently, the user will see the error 403 page (access denied).
Normally, the access callback is not defined, and by default Drupal will use `user_access()`.

Comment: `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,` can you tell me more about MENU_CALLBACK ...when and how to use it

Comment: That is a different question. `:)` Read [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) first, and ask a question if it is not clear what `MENU_CALLBACK` does.

Comment: Thanks for response ;) but already explored on that and found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For using predefined valid permissions, such as system permissions:

1. Check the list of valid permissions at: /admin/people/permissions

[image: D7 - Permission by Role]

3. Copy the permission string and add it to your 'access arguments' array:

   ```
   function mymodule_menu() {
       $items['admin/config/mymodule_config'] = [
           'title' => 'MyModule',
           'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
           'access callback' => '_mymodule_admin_form',
           'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
           'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
     ];

     return $items;
   }
   ```

Reference: [Valid access arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891054/valid-access-arguments/41028911#41028911)