# why this code can't work in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

this is my module file.

```
 function mymenu_menu() {
 $item=array();
  $item['welcome'] = array(
   'title' => 'welcome',
  'page callback' => 'mymenu_test',
 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 ); 

   return $item;
  }



  function mymenu_test(){
 $output = 'welcome user!';
 return $output;
 }
```

when i access example.com/welcome.  it show access denied, why?

Comment: Did you remember to clear the menu cache before testing?

Comment: i have cleared the cache, but it still can't work. when i add the 'access arguments'=>...it's ok. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this answer : [Can someone explain "access arguments" in Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018986/can-someone-explain-access-arguments-in-drupal/3048425#3048425) and take a look at [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6)

If you want to allow everyone access, you can also use `'access callback' => TRUE`