# Valid access arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I look up the valid access arguments? I looked in menu_router, but I believe that only gives some of them.

```
$items['admin/page'] = array(
   'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Invoke [`hook_permission()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) across all modules:

```
$permissions = module_invoke_all('permission');
```

If I remember rightly `array_keys($permissions)` will then give you a list of valid permission machine names. The labels/descriptions/other settings for each permissions are in each individual array item.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can look in the database?

Comment: Good question I've never actually looked before! They don't seem to be stored en masse in the db, rather associations between roles and permissions are stored in `role_permission`. My guess is that the permissions admin page calls `module_invoke_all('permission')` every time it's run and rebuilds the `role_permission` table on save. That way all of the permissions never need to be stored and Drupal can infer that a role without a permission entry in the table *doesn't* have access to the page/resource

Comment: This actually kind of makes sense thinking about it, if all the permissions were stored then Drupal would have to de-duplicate between the list it held in the database and all those provided by modules (which may have changed since the db was last updated)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are interested to the values of the access arguments where the access callback is "user_access" (the default value); as a module can use a different access callback, the values for the access arguments can theoretically be infinite.

The alternative to invoking all the implementations of `hook_permission()` is to use code similar to the following one:

```
$permissions = array();
db_query("SELECT permission FROM {role_permission}");

foreach ($result as $row) {
  $permissions[$row->permission] = TRUE;
}
```

`array_keys($permissions)` will then give you the list of all the permissions.

I took the query from [user_role_permissions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_role_permissions/7); the difference is that the function is interested in the permissions associated to the role passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

1- Check a list of valid permissions at: /admin/people/permissions

[image: Drupal 7, List of valid permissions]

2- Specify the permission in your menu hook:

```
function webforms_advanced_router_menu() {

  $items['admin/config/mymodule'] = [
    'title' => 'MyModule',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access callback' => '_mymodule_admin_form',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  ];

  return $items;
}
```